# Browser download gets cancelled on new ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am downloading a large file from server using a link in my app. When a new ajax call is made before the download is complete, the download file "get" request gets cancelled and the new ajax call is timed out.

```
<a href="file.pdf"></a>
```

Why the ajax call gets timed out?

Comment: And what's the question ?

Comment: Why the ajax call gets timed out?

Comment: The AJAX gets timed out because you are making a new non-XHR request. It's the same as clicking a link to go to another page; the browser will end any pending requests, regardless of whether they are for an image, stylesheet or an AJAX request.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: How can I prevent this? Is there any way to check whether download is in progress in client side?

Comment: We'd need more code but there's always a way to execute some code when you receive the answer from an ajax call.

Comment: @dystroy: But I need the ajax call to happen by cancelling out the download request before the ajax call?